# HEADPHONES choice - Audio Technica M40x vs Senheiser HD 558 vs Sony MDR-7506

Tags: headphones

Does it compensate the price difference between these headphones? (M40x 90 eur, HD558 121 eur, MDR-7506 87 eur)
This is for home use so open headphones are not a problem. My only concern are the design of the HD558, that I do not consider "pretty" headphones. I currently own an AKG K77, and I want to get the next level audio. What is your personal choice and why?

My budget is up to 120 eur max (in amazon.es).

Hope to receive your suggestions!

Comment: What will you be listening to with them?

Comment: @Evan I will use them to watch movies, tv series, and listen to music: deep house, techno, some classical music, and hip-hop. It is a wide set of styles, so I do not know what is the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Sony 7506/V6's and I like them a lot, but they can be a bit fatiguing, both for fit and for being a little harsh sounding. They have great big bass though and area  lot of fun and very clear. I wasn't a fan of the ATH-M50's when I heard them but lots of people like them. Beyerdynamic's simply don't fit my head, they are too small for me. In your price range it is worth checking out the Grado line (SR-60/80/125), some people love these, I'm not one of them but you could be. Sennheiser makes the HD280s around this price, also worth checking out as well as the HD-25's which are really nice but a little pricey. I use AKG K701's at home and I like them a lot for clarity and accuracy (which I really appreciate) but they aren't tons of "fun" and I usually listen to music on speakers.

Try to listen to as many different cans as you can before buying and don't be fooled by big boomy bass or overemphasized treble, listen for clarity and accuracy as well as a sound signature that you find pleasing. Visit your local shops and bring your own MP3 player or CD's. Check out head-fi.org for more extensive discussion and maybe even a local meetup if you are really into it.

Comment: I recently found the Shure SRH440, and I am leaning to choose them. What do you think?

Comment: I've never heard them but I certainly recommend testing multiple headphones before buying if you can. Research helps, but you can't know any headphones are to your taste until you try them. It sounds like you have an idea of what you don't like about your current AKG's so you should be looking for headphones that address your issues with them. It can be tricky to "know what your taste is" before having a lot of experience with various headphones too so you can do what I did and trade and upgrade for years before finding what you really want. I had 5 or 6 different headphones before my K701s.

Comment: http://www.headphone.com/products/shure-srh440
This is a good site and their reviews are trustworthy. I say go for them if they appeal to you. You may find that you don't like them and sell them and get something else but you just won't know unless you hear them.

Comment: And this: http://lifehacker.com/why-ive-stopped-relying-on-online-reviews-for-everythi-709600415

Answer (score 0):

If you want pretty, get ATH-M50, they are very good. (I know everyone says Sony 7506 but IMHO they are not good headphones at all...)

If you want the best sound on the range of sources as you listed, affordably, then get  Beyerdynamic DT-880 Pro (probably under $200 used, or $262 new here: http://bit.ly/BeyerdynamicDT880Pro)

Rather dorky looking but really the best I ever tried (out of many).

Comment: What do you think of the Shure SRH440?